# Summing Entries in Multiple Unequally-Sized Data Frames With Some (but not All) Rows and Columns the Same

Tags: r

I have the following three data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:10, B = 3:12, D = 4:13)
df2 <- data.frame(C = 1:5, B = 4:8, E = 2:6)
df3 <- data.frame(A = 13:10, B = 19:16, F = 1:4)

rownames(df1) <- paste0("row", seq_len(nrow(df1)))
rownames(df2) <- paste0("row", c(1, 3, 5, 7, 11))
rownames(df3) <- paste0("row", c(12, 3, 10, 9))

# > df1
#        A  B  D
# row1   1  3  4
# row2   2  4  5
# row3   3  5  6
# row4   4  6  7
# row5   5  7  8
# row6   6  8  9
# row7   7  9 10
# row8   8 10 11
# row9   9 11 12
# row10 10 12 13

# > df2
#       C B E
# row1  1 4 2
# row3  2 5 3
# row5  3 6 4
# row7  4 7 5
# row11 5 8 6

# > df3
#       A  B F
# row12 13 19 1
# row3  12 18 2
# row10 11 17 3
# row9  10 16 4
```

When cells from different data frames have the same row and column names, I want to sum their values. In the cases where a cell has no matches (there aren't any other cells with the same row and column name), the final data frame will contain that original value. When a cell with a particular row name and column name combination doesn't exist in any of the original data frames, the final data frame will contain an `NA` in that position.

The final data frame should look like this data frame:

```
> df4
       A  B  C  D  E  G
row1   1  7  1  4  2 NA
row2   2  4 NA  5  1 NA
row3  15 28  2  6  5  2
row4   4  6 NA  7  3 NA
row5   5 13  3  8  8 NA
row6   6  8 NA  9  5 NA
row7   7 16  4 10 11 NA
row8   8 10 NA 11  7 NA
row9  19 27 NA 12  8  4
row10 21 29 NA 13  9  3
row11 NA  8  5 NA  6 NA
row12 13 19 NA NA NA  1
```

I'm imagining something with the `Reduce()` function that can be used on many data frames at once. Is the first step adding missing rows and columns to existing data frames with `NA`s in all the cells where values are missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work. With row AND column names and one data type, I prefer matrices to data frames, but you can convert the final matrix back to a data frame if you need.

```
# put things in a list
df_list = list(df1, df2, df3)

# get the complete set of row and column names
all_rows = unique(unlist(lapply(df_list, rownames)))
all_cols = unique(unlist(lapply(df_list, colnames)))

# initialize a final matrix to NA
final_mat = matrix(NA, nrow = length(all_rows), ncol = length(all_cols))
rownames(final_mat) = all_rows
colnames(final_mat) = all_cols

# go through each df in the list
for(i in seq_along(df_list)) {
  # set any NAs in the selection to 0
  final_mat[rownames(df_list[[i]]), colnames(df_list[[i]])][is.na(final_mat[rownames(df_list[[i]]), colnames(df_list[[i]])])] = 0
  # add the data frame to the selection
  final_mat[rownames(df_list[[i]]), colnames(df_list[[i]])] = final_mat[rownames(df_list[[i]]), colnames(df_list[[i]])] + as.matrix(df_list[[i]])
}

final_mat
#        A  B  D  C  E  F
# row1   1  7  4  1  2 NA
# row2   2  4  5 NA NA NA
# row3  15 28  6  2  3  2
# row4   4  6  7 NA NA NA
# row5   5 13  8  3  4 NA
# row6   6  8  9 NA NA NA
# row7   7 16 10  4  5 NA
# row8   8 10 11 NA NA NA
# row9  19 27 12 NA NA  4
# row10 21 29 13 NA NA  3
# row11 NA  8 NA  5  6 NA
# row12 13 19 NA NA NA  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `dplyr` alternative -

- Put the dataframes in a list
- make rownames as a separate column from each dataframe
- Combine them in one dataframe
- For each rowname `sum` the values from all the columns. If a column has all the `NA`'s we return `NA`. A shortcut to do that is to use `hablar::sum_`.
- Order the data based on rownames
- Use `column_to_rownames` to assign the values back as rownames.

```
library(dplyr)

df_list = list(df1, df2, df3)

purrr::map_df(df_list, ~.x %>% rownames_to_column('row')) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(across(A:F, hablar::sum_)) %>%
  arrange(order(gtools::mixedorder(row))) %>%
  column_to_rownames('row')

#       A  B  D  C  E  F
#row1   1  7  4  1  2 NA
#row2   2  4  5 NA NA NA
#row3  15 28  6  2  3  2
#row4   4  6  7 NA NA NA
#row5   5 13  8  3  4 NA
#row6   6  8  9 NA NA NA
#row7   7 16 10  4  5 NA
#row8   8 10 11 NA NA NA
#row9  19 27 12 NA NA  4
#row10 21 29 13 NA NA  3
#row11 NA  8 NA  5  6 NA
#row12 13 19 NA NA NA  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE), 
           setDT(df2, keep.rownames = TRUE), 
         setDT(df3, keep.rownames = TRUE)), fill = TRUE)[, 
    lapply(.SD, function(x) dplyr::na_if(sum(x, na.rm = TRUE), 0)), rn]
```